# D3 How to refresh after image href of pattern is updated?

Tags: d3.js

I do not want to update my data. When the image of my href has changed I can see no way how to get the new image display in D3. If I change the name of the file and then change the path of the href I get the new pic. But that is what I do not want to do. Is there a way to tell D3 that the image in the file system has been updated?

Answer (score 0):

You could recreate your image at regular intervals, using [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) to call the creation/update function.